# MS MVC3 Nested EditorFor and View Templates with same ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, templates, viewmodel, editorfor

I have a hierarchy of Models I need to render out editors for.

I want to have a nice ViewModel that contains all the info needed for each part of the hierarchy to render itself and have that ViewModel get passed down the chain of templates.

I have strongly typed View to that ViewModel, and I can get to the first level of nesting fine:

MyView.cshtml:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x, "ViewTemplateA", "ViewTemplateA")
```

Within EditorTemplates/ViewTemplateA.cshtml:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(x => x, "ViewTemplateB", "ViewTemplateB")
```

---works OK up to here, ViewTemplateA gets rendered--

EditorTemplates/ViewTemplateB.cshtml:

```
@model MyViewModel
...etc...
```

-- ViewTemplateB never gets called. If I change it's `@model` to something else, and pass in a different object to match, such as `x => x.SubModel`, it gets called.

Any ideas??